# Django: Auto logout when Tab is closed (Not browser)

Tags: python, django

I've used the following line of code to make my browser log a user out of the Django admin when the browser is closed

`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting to true`

How do I change this and make it in such a way that when the user closes the tab, The user gets logged out?

Comment: Browsers have a feature to remove a cookie at close. They don't have that for tabs. You can of cause implement a Java Script that removes the cookie when the pae is closed. This would log out all open tabs of the page.

Comment: Ssup dude... Can you mail me the ES lab 7 answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely nothing to do with Django. It is more related to how browsers treat a cookie.

What happens is that if a cookie doesn't have an expiration date (`Expires` attribute) or `Max-Age`, browsers treat them as **session cookies**. That means a browser will delete that cookie when you exit your **browser session** i.e. when you close your browser.

And since closing a tab isn't equal to exiting your browser, browsers don't delete a session cookie.

---

---

---

**UPDATE:** If someone *really* needs to log the user out on tab close, it can be achieved, well, sort of.

You can set the session cookie's age to a small number, maybe 10 minutes. While the user has the tab opened, every 10 minutes, you refresh the cookie (i.e. make an AJAX requests to get a new cookie).

When the user closes the tab, their session will automatically expire within next 10 minutes.

It's a little complicated setup, but I've seen it implemented on banking sites etc. It's up to you to decide if it's worth it for your site or not.